# How to get list of subelements that are only one level deep from Python3 xml.etree.Element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

If I have a Python3 `xml.etree.Element` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects)), is it possible to get a list (or iterable, or whatever) of child elements to that `Element`, but ***only*** one level deep? If so, how can I do this?

(Note: it appears the `xml.etree.Element` library is essentially the same for the version of Python I'm using (3.6.8) and the latest version (3.11).)

---

For example, say I have this xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
  <name>myName</name>
  <SomeLevel1Element>
    <SomeLevel2Element>foo</SomeLevel2Element>
  </SomeLevel1Element>
  <SomeLevel1Element>
    <SomeLevel2Element>bar</SomeLevel2Element>
  </SomeLevel1Element>
  <AnotherLevel1Element>
  </AnotherLevel1Element>
</Document>
```

I want to do something like:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(PATH_TO_XML_FILE)
root = tree.getroot()
direct_children_of_root = <something>
for child in direct_children_of_root:
  print(child)

"""
<Element 'name' at 0x123abc>
<Element 'SomeLevel1Element' at 0x123bbc>
<Element 'SomeLevel1Element' at 0x123cbc>
<Element 'AnotherLevel1Element' at 0x123dbc>
"""
```

---

I cannot use `findall()`, `find()`, `findtext()`, since I may not know the amount or kinds of child elements of `root`.

---

I cannot use `iter()`, since that method appears to give ***all*** children of ***all*** children elements.

For example, using the same xml as above:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(PATH_TO_XML_FILE)
root = tree.getroot()
elems = root.iter()
for e in elems:
  print(e)

"""
<Element 'Document' at 0x123abc>
<Element 'name' at 0x123bbc>
<Element 'SomeLevel1Element' at 0x123cbc>
<Element 'SomeLevel2Element' at 0x123dbc>
<Element 'SomeLevel1Element' at 0x123ebc>
<Element 'SomeLevel2Element' at 0x123fbc>
<Element 'AnotherLevel1Element' at 0x124abc>
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` has [limited support](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) for Xpath.
Using `lxml` instead

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.parse('tmp.xml')
>>> parentName = doc.getroot().tag
>>> level1 = doc.xpath(f'//*[parent::{parentName}]')
>>> for e in level1:
...     print(e.tag)
... 
name
SomeLevel1Element
SomeLevel1Element
AnotherLevel1Element
```

If `xml.etree.ElementTree` is required

```
>>> level1 = root.findall('.')[0].findall('./*')
>>> for e in level1:
...     print(e.tag)
... 
name
SomeLevel1Element
SomeLevel1Element
AnotherLevel1Element
```

Answer (score 0):

`list(root)` returns a list with the children of `root`.

```py
direct_children_of_root = list(root)
for child in direct_children_of_root:
    print(child)
```

Even simpler is to just iterate over `root` directly.

```
for child in root:
    print(child)
```